# Include js library in nuxt.config.js with Assets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

**I'm trying to include some javascript files but for some reason, I get this**

> " error in GET http://localhost:3000/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

**I don't know if this is the better way to Include the javascript file please if someone can help me out.**

```
     head: {
    title: 'streamit',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: '/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', type: 'text/javascript' },
    
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/images/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
```

> assets/ js/ jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Comment: `jquery-3.4.1min.js` != `jquery-3.4.1.min.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this and make sure `static` folder and create `js` floder inside it and put your `jquery-3.4.1.min.js` file there. In your `nuxt.config.js` put :

```
script: [
  { src: 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a new folder called static and I put inside it all js files and then

```
script: [
      { src: './js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', type: 'text/javascript' },
    
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

For `"nuxt": "^3.6.5"`:

Try Like this and make sure `public` folder and create `js` folder inside it and put your `jquery-3.4.1.min.js` file there. In your `nuxt.config.js` put :

```js
    script: [
      { src: 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' },
    ]
```

Folder structure screenshot:

[image]